# Indexer - Explicit Interface Member Implementation

Tags: c#, interface, indexer, explicit-interface

I would need an working example-program of an Explicit Interface Member Implementation of an Indexer.

[Microsofts c# docu of Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/indexers-in-interfaces) states that this is possible, but does not provide a working example (at least for me the example is not working). I would need a working Program that does that.

Comment: "for me the example is not working". What's not working? What errors do you get? It seems quite simple straight-forward code, so if it doesn't work, show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation seems to be wrong. I can’t check it now and I don’t recall ever implementing explicitly an indexer, but this should work:

```
interface IInterface
{
    ReturnType this[int index] { get; }
}

class Foo: IInterface
{
    ReturnType IInterface.this[int index]
    {
        get { return ... }
    }
}
```